# backbone server returning html

Tags: ajax, json, backbone.js, get, fetch

I've set up simple back bone code were I'm fetching from a directory which contains images -

url: 'uploads/'

the fetch is succesful, but my results basically contains an `html` list of the images in the directory

like :

```
<h1>Index of /backbone_images/uploads</h1>
<ul><li><a href="/backbone_images/"> Parent Directory</a></li>
<li><a href="2012-12-11%2015.30.221.jpg"> 2012-12-11 15.30.221.jpg</a></li>
<li><a href="ian1.jpg"> in1.jpg</a></li>
<li><a href="imagedummy.png"> imagedummy.png</a></li>
```

A) Should the server be returning JSON if fetching from a directory of images?
B) If not is there an easy way to convert this HTML response to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) You should setup your server so that it returns JSON. You can easily test this by going to the url using your browser, you should get something like:

```
{"Parent Directory":[{"link":"2012-12-11%2015.30.221.jpg", text:"2012-12-11 15.30.221.jpg"},{"link":"ian1.jpg", text:"ian1.jpg"},{"link":"imagedummy.png", text:"imagedummy.png"}]}
```

It's up to you to define how you want to structure you JSON message. How you do that depends of the technology you're using on your server and has nothing to do with backbone. You need to post more details if you need more help.

B) As far a I know, there is no easy way to automatically convert from HTML to JSON. How to do it depends how what you're using on the server side.

Comment: Ok, so basically now instead of trying to go to the directory, I'm fetching from a PHP file which lists the images in the directory and returns the list as JSON, the results are : '[".","..",".DS_Store","2012-12-11 15.30.221.jpg","ian1.jpg","imagedummy.png"] , but I wish that it would ignore the .ds_store and the '.'

Comment: ok you were right this was a server issue (AKA I pointed to a PHP file)